# У меня есть сайт с формой авторизации, хочу к нему привязать сертификат.

Tags: ssl

У меня есть сайт с формой авторизации, хочу к нему привязать сертификат. 
Вот смотрю на многих сайтах реализовано так, все страницы сайта работают по http, но при переходе на страницу например /login перебрасывает на напрмер https://ssl.example.com/login, после прохождения авторизации вновь перебрасывает на http. Вопрос, зачем так реализуют? И на какие страницы тогда если что делать такое перенаправление? Вот пример olx.ua

И еще вопрос. В Chrome при нажатии на зеленый замочек в адресной строке пишет что соединение зашифровано с помощью устаревших наборов шифров. Как это исправить?

Comment: по поводу устаревших наборов шифров так и не понял, это проблема сертификата или настроек nginx?

Answer (score 1):

> Вопрос, зачем так реализуют?

Предполагаю, чтобы распределить нагрузку, плюс модульность: отдельный сервис для авторизации/регистрации.

> В Chrome при нажатии на зеленый замочек в адресной строке пишет что
>   соединение зашифровано с помощью устаревших наборов шифров.

Купить сертификат с не устаревшим методом шифрования и установить на сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Переброс с HTTP (нешифрованное соединение) на HTTPS (шифрованное соединение) на формах логина используется для защиты передаваемых данных. Передача данных по HTTP открыта и её элементарно перехватить в любой точке пути и даже подслушать через пассивный приём Wi-Fi, если клиент через него работает. Передача данных по HTTPS предполагает (по крайней мере, теоретически), что данные доступны только клиенту и серверу и никто, перехватив, не сможет их расшифровать.

Что касается устаревших наборов шифров, то, вероятно, таковы настройки вашего HTTP-сервера. На нём просто нужно включить более стойкие методы шифрования. Как это сделать, зависит от конкретного используемого сервера и является темой для другого вопроса.

Comment: ну зачем нужен https я знаю. Просто думаю как лучше, весь контент сайта перевести на https или только авторизацию пользователей? Как будет провельнее?

Comment: HTTPS увеличивает нагрузку на сервер. Если нет конфиденциальных данных, то лучше авторизовать по HTTPS, а обычный контент гнать по HTTP.

Comment: ок, спасибо, теперь все понятно